# How to fix 'Duplicate identifier prototype'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to extend some methods in my angular app, but when i try to use prototype, it seems that not recognize the word 'prototype'.

Does anyone has any fix or solution workaround??

```
  interface Function {
      RenderActionButtons() : any;      
  }

  Function.prototype.RenderActionButtons = function() {
  }
```

Comment: Extending native prototypes is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @JonasWilms do you have any solution or workaround?

Comment: Why do you need `(function () { }).RenderActionButto s()` ? Whats the usecase?

Comment: @JonasWilms i'm working with ag-grid and in that component if you want to template come columns, you have to extend some interfaces: https://www.ag-grid.co.uk/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/ 

But i was figuring out how to implement it with typescript... i already found another solution thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You declare your interface and then declare new class and implement that method.

```
interface Function {
  RenderActionButtons : ()=>void;      
}
Class test implement Function{
   Public RenderActionButtons(){}
}
```